# Login on Central Management Console (Business Objects XI)

Tags: business-objects

I recent installed Business Objects Edge (trial version), and I am trying log on the console (CMC)
I don't know the user and pass, because during the installation, the installer doesn't ask me anything about this. Only the pass for the 'CMS'.

I would like know what is the user and pass correct, ie., where I can search them.

Also, I need an user and a password for all the tools: Designer, Destkop Intelligence, Publishing Wizard, ...

Sorry for my english...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just I find the user ... 'Administrator'
Now, I'm feel like a stupid...